# Actionscript 3 Flash Keyboard Event

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, events, textinput

I wonder could some one enlighten me on an easier way of solving this code.I am new to flash and actionscript.

I want to have a text box, where a user enters their name. Each time a charachter is pressed, and image of that letter is displayed below the text box.  So for example. user rights john.  John is displayed in nice images below.

I have got this working, but I have to create a input box for each character, so I am left with eg. 6 boxes for each letter of name, that will only accept a character each.  The reason for this is, I cannot place the images after each other, they keep overwriting the position of the 1st character typed, if only one single textbox is used.

I know i am going the long way around this, there must be something alot easier.

Here is the code, it will be very tedious if I have to go this route. Could someon give me a quick hinter on the correct way to go about this.

Thanks
Fintan

```
////////////////111111////////////////////
firstname.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, key_pressed);
function key_pressed(event:KeyboardEvent):void {
if (event.charCode == 65) {
    var fl_MyInstance_2:LibrarySymbol = new LibrarySymbol();
        fl_MyInstance_2.x = 50
        fl_MyInstance_2.y = 200
        addChild(fl_MyInstance_2);

} else if (event.charCode == 66) {
    var fl_MyInstance_3:letterb = new letterb();
        fl_MyInstance_3.x = 50
        fl_MyInstance_3.y = 200
    addChild(fl_MyInstance_3);

} else if (event.charCode == 67) {
    var fl_MyInstance_4:letterc = new letterc();
        fl_MyInstance_4.x = 50
        fl_MyInstance_4.y = 200
    addChild(fl_MyInstance_4);

} else if (event.charCode == 68) {
    var fl_MyInstance_5:letterd = new letterd();
        fl_MyInstance_5.x = 50
        fl_MyInstance_5.y = 200
    addChild(fl_MyInstance_5);

} else if (event.charCode == 69) {
    var fl_MyInstance_6:letterd = new letterd();
        fl_MyInstance_6.x = 50
        fl_MyInstance_6.y = 200
    addChild(fl_MyInstance_6);  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll give you some code and some hints to try to point you to the right direction.

First of all, you don't need one different class for each alphabet letter - that would be at least 26 classes, or 52 if you take into account upper case/lower case, and it's totally unnecessary because each and all only serve one purpose - to show one letter.

What I would do instead is to make one MovieClip with 26 different frames (or 52 if upper/lower cases)  labelled "a" to "z" (or "A" to "z"). In each of those frames, put the drawing of one letter, and one `stop();`. Link only this MovieClip to a class - Letter, or whatever.

Then, when the user writes on your firstname TextField, you have to be careful because he/she can hit other keys that are not letters - for example, the del key, back arrow, etc that might mess up with your visual representation. I think the only way to make sure you display everything right is to draw each time the whole contents of the textfield, like this:

```
//KEY UP EVENT
firstname.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, key_pressed);

//container (empty) movieclip
var container_mc:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
addChild(container_mc);

function key_pressed(e:KeyboardEvent):void 
{

  var offset:Number=0;

  //clear container to update visual representation
  while(container_mc.numChildren>0)
    container_mc.removeChildAt(0);

  var letterInstance:Letter; //your linked class

  for(var i:uint=0;i<firstname.text.length;i++)
  {  
     letterInstance = new Letter();

     //go to frame corresponding to the letter at position "i"
     //OR use your own system to choose the image for each letter!
     letterInstance.gotoAndStop(first_name.text.charAt(i));

     //postion: x (plus offset to avoid overwritting), y
     letterInstance.x = 50 + offset;
     offset+= letterInstance.width;
     letterInstance.y = 200;

     //add letter to container
     container_mc.addChild(letterInstance);
   }

}
```

This code still has some problems, like names with non-letter characters like whitespaces, apostrophes, etc, but I think you can start working from here ;)

Hope to be of some help, good luck!

Comment: Glad to help mate, if this answer solved your problem, a green checkie (accept) would be much appreciated! ;)

Answer (score 1):

You say "So for example. user rights john. John is displayed in nice images below." So if I understand you correctly you want to display pre-rendered Bitmap images of the characters the user has typed?

If this is the case consider the following:

```
private var _image:Sprite = new Sprite(); // a container to hold your bitmaps (jpgs/pngs)
private var _spacing:uint = 30; // some arbitrary value to space them apart //
myInputTextField.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, onNameChange);

function onNameChange(e:Event):void
{
// first clear the image sprite to accommodate things like backspaces //
    while(_image.numChildren) _image.removeChildAt(0);
// get the current string in the input textfield //
    var s:String = myInputTextField.text;
// and then layout a series of pre-rendered bitmaps based on those characters //
    for (var i:uint=0; i<s.length; i++){
        var c:String = s.substr(i, 1); // one character //
        var b:Bitmap = getImageCharacter(c);
            b.x = _spacing * i;
        _image.addChild(b);
    }
}
```

The following helper function is just a map that takes a character and maps it to a BitmapData object that say could be in your library.

```
function getImageCharacter(s:String):Bitmap
{  
    switch(s){
        case a: return new Bitmap(new ImageA()); break;
        case b: return new Bitmap(new ImageB()); break;
        case c: return new Bitmap(new ImageC()); break;
    }
}
```

In this case ImageA could be a .png file in your library that was set to export as "ImageA".

This is just a simple example that could be much more optimized but this should get you started down the right path.

Comment: Thanks for your help Braitsch.  I couldnt figure out the public/private vars, I kept getting error 1013 /1114. So I used the movie suggestion below.